# Wait and Notify

Tags: java, wait, notify

If the main thread quits before child finishes its work, and child tries to notify, what will happen?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you only have 2 threads? One main thread, and one deamon thread? What are they doing? (code examples are will help here).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here I have single thread.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call [`notify()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) on an object that no other thread called `wait()` on, then the `notify` call will have no effect.

Comment: Right. Another way to say it is that if the main thread has finished, it can not have called wait on an object that the child has yet to notify.